# How to filter subnets according to a VPC in CloudFormation's parameters section?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to list out the subnets only from specific VPC in my cloudformation parameters section:

```
VPC:
    Description: VPC Id
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id 

Subnets:
    Description: Select Subnets (Minimum 2)
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
```

The above displays all subnets (from other subnets also) but I want to show only subnets from selected VPC.

Is it possible? What is the workaround for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *list* them that way, but you can prevent deployment if the chosen subnets are not in the VPC by using a CloudFormation rule:

```
{
  "Rules": {
    "IsSubnetInsideVPC": {
      "Assertions": [
        {
          "Assert": {
            "Fn::EachMemberEquals" : [
              {
                "Fn::ValueOfAll": [
                  "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id",
                  "VpcId"
                ]
              },
              {
                "Ref": "VPC"
              }
            ]
          },
          "AssertDescription": "One or more subnets you selected are not in the VPC"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```